# Web Api 2.0 OAuth 2.0 Testing with Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth

I am currently integrating various OAuth providers for integration on a Web Api 2.0. My integration is based on this implementation;

[ASP.NET Web API 2 external logins with Facebook and Google in AngularJS app](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/)

Now I am trying to test my facebook implementation. Using Postman, I have sent the GET to my /ExternalLogin endpoint and the challenge has been returned as a redirect.

I saved the returned html to a .html file and loaded this up. This loads the facebook login screen, where I then enter my username and password for to grant access.

However, when I click login I get a ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND?

I want to debug and test the workflow of being called back using postman (I dont want to simply use postman to create a facebook token, I want to ensure that my app behaves correctly when facebook makes the callback with the token after the grant has been made).

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you need postman to test this? Are you trying to set up automated testing, or what?

Comment: @CBroe I'm trying to just test the end to end result of the process (without a front end), I'm new to this so any advice on testing this process woul dbe great. I have resolved the ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND as it was simply not appending the facebook.com domain, However, even though I then get the facebook access screen, click to allow access its returning a 'access_denied' message back to the api? Any ideas why? If i log into facebook the app is listed there?

Comment: Probably because of your weird test approach. A locally saved page doesn’t have access to the cookies of the domain it would normally run under, etc. I have never seen or heard of anyone trying to test Facebook login this way, and I can hardly see it making any sense. And “without frontend” hardly makes any sense either - the Facebook login *requires* user interaction in some sort of browser or webview. So why are you not testing _that_?